# Finding a mapping between two types of (generalized) hypergeometric series

Tags: pattern-matching, special-functions, series-expansion

I am given two functions, one is of the form $2F1(a,b,c;z)$, where $2F1$ is a hypergeometric series. The other one is a generalized hypergeometric series $3F2(d,e,f;g,h;w)$, where the characters are certain (specific) parameters. Is it possible to use mathematica to find the mapping between those two functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you know of any mathematica tool which can be used for this? To be specific the functions are given by $2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{4} ;-\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)$ and $_3F_2\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{6},\frac{3}{2};\frac{-27}{2x^6}\right)$.

Comment: What do you mean by mapping? What kind of answer would you consider satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(f21[x_] =
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 5/4, -1/x^4]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(f32[x_] =
   HypergeometricPFQ[{1/6, 1/3, 2/3}, {7/6, 
     3/2}, -27/(2 x^6)]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Both functions have even symmetry

```
f21[x] == f21[-x] && f32[x] == f32[-x]

(* True *)
```

Both functions asymptotically approach `1` from below

```
Asymptotic[#, {x, Infinity, 6}] & /@ {f21[x], f32[x]}

(* {1 - 1/(10 x^4), 1 - 2/(7 x^6)} *)
```

Graphically,

```
xmax = 2;

Plot[{f21[x], f32[x]}, {x, 0, xmax},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.6, 0.4}]]
```

[image]

You can use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) to map from one function to the other

```
Legended[
 ParametricPlot[{f21[x], f32[x]}, {x, 0, xmax},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
     {HoldForm[f21[x]], 
      HoldForm[f32[x]]}),
  PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{f21, f32, x},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][x/xmax]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  Epilog -> {Lighter[Gray, 0.5], Dashed,
    Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}],
 Placed[
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, xmax}},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 175,
   LegendLabel -> Style[x, 14, Bold]],
  {0.2, 0.625}]]
```

[image]